# Displaying a json array as a table, sorted by date (with a date row as an header)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**So here is the scenario:**
I have a json array of shows (***sorted by date***), each show is a json with all the show's details (including the show's exact date (a JavaScript date object).
I want to display all the shows as a table sorted by date, with a date header before all the date's show. something like this:

- date: 18/2

  - 4:00 | show_name | show_location
  - 5:00 | show_name | show_location
  - 6:00 | show_name | show_location
- date: 19/2

  - 2:00 | show_name | show_location
  - 3:00 | show_name | show_location
  - 4:30 | show_name | show_location
- date: 20/2

  - 12:30  | show_name | show_location
  - 3:00   | show_name | show_location
  - 5:00   | show_name | show_location

---

Right now, the only way I thought of doing this is iterating all the shows, and for each show, inserting it into a map, with the key as the date and the value an array of shows of that date. then creating another array (for the ng-repeat), containing for each day, a json with the day and array of shows. then displaying the last array in the table with angular's ng-repeat

here is the code:

```
<script> 
var shows = [{name:"...",location:"...",date:<dateObject>},{name:"...",location:"...",date:<dateObject>},{},{},{},...];
var map = {};
var $scope.daysArray = []
shows.forEach(function(show){
    var date = show.getLocaleDateString(); //the key of the map is the date portion of the JS Date Object
    if (!map[date]) 
    {
        map[date] = [];
    }
    map[date].push(show);
});


for (date in map)
{
    $scope.daysArray.push({date: date ,shows: map[date]}); 
}
</script>
```

---

```
<html>
....
<table>
    <tbody ng-repeat="day in daysArray">
            <tr><td>{{day.date}}<td></tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="show in day.shows">
                <td>{{show.time}}</td>
                <td>{{show.name}}</td>
                <td>{{show.location}}</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


</html>
```

---

### Is there a more simple / elegant solution to this with angular ?

I would love just to do this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="show in shows">
        <td>{{show.time}}</td>
        <td>{{show.name}}</td>
        <td>{{show.location}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But how can I add the date tr header before the shows with the same date ? 
Thanks !

Comment: The shows are already sorted, the only problem is the tr header before the shows with the same date.

Comment: show sample data . Can use `groupBy` filter but need to see how dates are defined/formatted